# javascript SlickGrid column width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

I am trying to implement a simple editable table using SlickGrid using example1_simple (found here http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html) as a template, but its gone terribly wrong.

My grid has to fit within a tab on the form that is 280 pixels wide and will have 3 columns (id, X, Y). The id will be autoincrementing and x & y will be blank, but for testing I am putting a gradually lengthening string in each cell so on the first row it should read 0, a, b and the second row would contain 1, aa, bb, etc. However each cell is being drawn below the previous, so that row 1 contains '0', row 2 contains '1' and 'a' drawn over each other, and row 3 contains '2', 'aa', and 'b' and so on. I've temporarily put it up on my website http://www.nutanageophysics.com/IFP/test.html so everyone can see. (quick side question - what's best way to preserve live examples such as this?)

Here's my test html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Nutana Project Planner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slick.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slick.grid.js"></script>
    <script src="js/xyGrid.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var xyGrid;

      function initialize() {
        xyGrid = new Slick.Grid("#xyGrid", data, columns, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize();">
    <div id=xyGrid >
        <!-- the grid is going to be placed here by onLoadXML -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My SlickGrid code is in xyGrid.js, included here:

```
  var data = [];
  var columns = [
    {id: "id", name: "id", field: "id"},
    {id: "x1", name: "X", field: "x1"},
    {id: "y1", name: "Y", field: "y1"},
  ];

   var options = {
      enableCellNavigation: true,
      enableColumnReorder: false,
  };

  $(function () {
      var a='a';
      var b='b';
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      data[i] = {
        id:  i,
        x1: a,
        y1: b,
      };
      a +="a";
      b += "b";
    }

  })
```

The only other possible relevant thing is i've defined the style for xyGrid in css as

```
  #xyGrid {
   width: 280px;
   height: 500px;
  }
```

I've tried changing the width to no effect. All of the other relevant css is in the jquery.ui.css which I haven't touched. I've also unsuccessfully tried a bunch of different Grid options, but the two used here are those used in the example. I've also built a table around my div as in the example but they were using the table for other purposes and it isn't relevant.

Please help.

Thanks,

Marc Pelletier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're missing the stylesheet: 
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css

I re-created it locally and it looks okay with that included. Double-check you have all the sheets and scripts included in the original example.

(You can use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) for some sample code. Not sure if it could accommodate all this!)